# Populate datagridview of another form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, populate

In an attempt to fix my [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475030/backgroundworker-freezes-ui-vb-net), i tried to move Form2's(contacts) load event codes to form1's background worker...The code is :

```
Private Sub Contact_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Con.open
    dim cmd as new sqlcommand("Select * from Users",con)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(table)
    datagrid2.DataSource = table
    con.Close()
    datagrid2.Columns(0).Frozen = True
    datagrid2.Columns(0).Width = 48
    datagrid2.Columns(1).Width = 33
    AddSelectAllCheckBox(datagrid2)
    Dim img As DataGridViewImageColumn
    img = datagrid2.Columns(1)
    img.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
    ExtensionMethods2.DoubleBuffered(datagrid2, True)
    ExtensionMethods1.DoubleBuffered(Panel3, True)
    ExtensionMethods1.DoubleBuffered(Panel9, True)
    mymy1.DoubleBuffered(inpeople, True)
    If datagrid2.Rows.Count <= 0 Then
        added.Visible = True
    Else
        added.Visible = False
    End If
    Try
        MetroComboBox2.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\ct_list.ofptx"))
        moneylist.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\cr_list.ofptx"))
        ttlist.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\tt_list.ofptx"))
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("One or more files required by OffPo is missing/corrupted" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "Error occured in : ct_list.ofptx or cr_list.ofptx")
    End Try
    entrylabel.Text = "There are/is " & datagrid2.Rows.Count & " contact entries"
    svbtn.Enabled = False
    upbtn.Enabled = False
    dtb.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

To fix my previous problem(to fix the BACKGROUND WORKER FREEZING UI issue), i moved this code to the form1's BackGroundWorker's DoWork event. The code for RunCompleted event looks like this :

```
     Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerCompleted
    Contact.Show()
    waiting.Hide()
End Sub
```

The problem is, when BackGroundWorker shows the Form2(contacts), the datagridview becomes empty.It only loads the column names but no rows/data...What am i missing ?? Why isn't the dgvw populating ?

**I didn't add the BackGroundWorker Do_work event's code as it is the same as Form2's load event code**

Comment: The whole point of a `BackgroundWorker` is to do background work. Anything related to the UI is inherently foreground work.  You don't do anything related to the UI in the `DoWork` event handler.  It's intended for things like reading data from files and databases, but you don't actually display the data from that event handler. Any changes to the UI are done in the `ProgressChanged` and/or `RunWorkerCompleted` event handlers.  See this: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889-Using-the-BackgroundWorker-Component

Comment: so, i can't apply the form2's load event code to background worker's dowork event ?? Then my PREVIOUS PROBLEM stays unsolved

Comment: I said what I meant and I meant what I said. You can't touch the UI in the `DoWork` event handler. Any code that touches the UI cannot go there. Any code that doesn't touch the UI, potentially can go there. It's up to you to separate the two and determine whether it is beneficial to move what can and do the rest in the other two event handlers.

Comment: Have you looked into my previous problem/question ? If i use the RunWorkerCompleted event,then i face the PREVIOUS PROBLEM....any fix to either this issue or the previous issue ?

Comment: How many records are you populating in the datagrid?

Comment: I have looked and I have commented. It's not using `RunWorkerCompleted` that's the problem.  It's using it improperly. Have you followed the link I provided? If not, why not?